# How to write binary data to a compressed file

Tags: c++, zlib, compression, bzip2, boost-iostreams

I have some financial data that I am processing in C++. I am storing it in a simple binary format because it requires fewer resources and is fast, however I would like to add compression to the file. I am guessing I will be IO bound so the compression won't cost me much in terms of processing speed.

I have no idea how to do the compression, as I am an academic and not a real programmer. I could really use some hand holding on this one.

```
I have my data in a structure like this:

  struct TradesBin {
    int ttim;
    int prc;
    int siz;
    short int g127;
    short int corr;
    char cond[2];
    char ex[1];
}__attribute__((packed));
```

Which I can write to a binary file as follows:

```
ofstream fout(outfile.c_str(), ios::out | ios::binary);
fout.write((char *) &tbin, sizeof(TradesBin));
```

Where tbin is filled with TradesBin data.

How do I now add compression to these files?  I have heard only vaguely of things like ZLO, Bzip2, zlib, and Boost.IOStreams.  I much appreciate your guidance and suggestions!

Thank you!

Comment: Zlib is what you want to use, but, unfortunately, using it is a bit tricky, since it's run in a kind of coroutine fashion.  Of course, simpler is to write flat files and then zip them with compression.

Comment: Boost has a [zlib filter](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/zlib.html) that lets you use zlib on top of a normal C++ stream. However, are you sure you need compression? [Premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) and all...

Comment: @HotLicks: No coroutines needed. Just recently I dealt with code like that for (large) amount of simple numeric data where we read / write bunches of doubles.

Comment: Zlib is a good fit almost anywhere if you're in a crunch. If space is that important, you probably want to 'disassemble' your structs anyway and write only the raw bytes of each datum; not the struct with whatever the byte-packing flavor-of-the-build is. Its a good idea to do it anyway, literally down to byte-by-byte, to ensure reading on a different platform (big vs. little endian, as an example) will be seamless and completely portable.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel -- I said "a kind of coroutine fashion" -- you have to feed the data in a poor-man's queue, not in logical blocks.

Comment: @HotLicks: Well I have passed gigabytes of data through essentially the same construct I show below, without any need for queues.  So I still consider your conjecture unproven.  Would you be able to point to some examples?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel -- Don't have the code with me, but I'm talking about the low-level interfaces.  gzwrite probably hides all that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zlib allows you to do this, but it is provides only a plain C interface. In a nutshell, you do

```
gzFile fp = gzopen(fname.c_str(),"wb");
gzwrite(fp, (void*) (&vec[0]), sizeof(TradesBin)*nelem);
gzclose(fp);
```

where `vec` would be for example a `std::vector<TradesBin>` for your `TradesBin` structure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am almost "there" with implementing your approach.  However, I get an compilation error stating that "there is no suitable conversion from std::vector<TradesBin, std::allocator<TradesBin>> to "voidpc".  Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, it so happens that I had to do that too. Updating answer ... and please feel free to upvote and accept :)